# Using JGIT to push changes to the remote Github repository

Tags: git, github, push, git-push, jgit

I'm new to git and I am trying to push my committed changes to the github repository.
Here is the code snippet:

```
    Git git = Git.init().setDirectory(localPath).call();
    git.add().addFilepattern(".").call();
    git.add().setUpdate(true).addFilepattern(".").call();
    Status status = git.status().call();
    Set<String> added = status.getAdded();
    Set<String> uncommittedChanges = status.getUncommittedChanges();

    git.commit().setAllowEmpty(true).setAll(true).setNoVerify(true).setMessage(commitMessage).call();
    CredentialsProvider cp = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(username, password); 
    StoredConfig storedConfig = git.getRepository().getConfig();
    storedConfig.setBoolean( "http", null, "sslVerify", false );
    storedConfig.save();
    git.push().setRemote(gitURL).setCredentialsProvider(cp).call();
```

If I use a newly created Github repository and give that gitURL then all the contents are pushed as expected.
However, if I already have an existing Github repository with some contents inside it, this doesn't push nor throws any error.
I even tried to use setForce `git.push().setForce(true).setRemote(gitURL).setCredentialsProvider(cp).call()`
but with this it overwrites the new contents to my Github repo and it's previous contents are lost.

I would like to know what changes should I make here so that my Github repository is pushed with the new changes and the old contents of this repo remain as well?

Comment: The data structure returned by push() tells you what the command did and why it didn‘t do what you may have expected.

Comment: To add commits to a remote repository, you first need to clone it, then merge or rebase you changes locally with the remote branch, then you can push without ‚force‘.

Comment: Yup thank you! That worked.